# Accesing table in VS 2013 C#

Tags: c#, database, row

I want to do a login form in C# and a problem occurred. I want to search all rows of table but I get an error. I have done it two minutes earlier and it worked. Tried to re-do it and it failed. I have no idea how to set up the reference to database object (I didn't do it the first time and somehow it worked).

Line of code with error :

```
foreach (DataRow row in LoginsDataSet.Loginy)
```

error text:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or...

Comment: What is `LoginsDataSet` exaclty? Could you please show it's definition?

Comment: Your error message states that the `LoginsDataSet` is not an object instance. It s probably the class name.

Comment: i have created database called Logins and then andded data source called LoginsDataSet connected to database Logins

Comment: i forgot about this :P sorry
LoginsDataSet dane = new LoginsDataSet();

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in comment your `DataSet` instance variable is `dane`, then you must use something like this:

```
foreach(DataRow row in dane.Loginy.Rows)
{
    ....
}
```

in case if you have strongly typed dataset you may have something like this:

```
foreach(LoginsDataSet.LoginyRow row in dane.Loginy)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: there is no error but i don't know why it doesn't start the foreach loop (i tested it by puting show messagebox inside)